# Testing equality of means of dependent samples

Tags: r, t-test

I have two samples, one is on the stock YUM (which is a constituent of the S&P500 market index) and another on S&P500. Both samples are from the same time period 2014-2018. I computed the log returns from the prices given on both samples. I am thinking of using the t-test to test if the means are equal, but i'm not sure if the dependency between the samples will affect the reliability of the results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a paired t-test here unless you have a match between each data point in one sample to a specific data point in the other sample. What you probably need here is a correlation.

Comment: would I just proceed with the normal independent t-test?

Comment: How many observations do you have in the YUM and in the S&P500 groups?

Comment: I have 1000 observations for each group!

Comment: Great. So if those 1000 time points are the same for the YUM and S&P500, use a paired t-test; if they are not the same, use the independent t-test.

Comment: ah I see, I did select the same time period for both sample, I will use paired test!